# loss not reducing in tensorflow classification attempt

Tags: python, tensorflow, machine-learning, keras

I wanted to simulate classifying whether a student will pass or fail a course depending on training data with a single input, namely a student's exam score.

I start by creating data set of test scores for 1000 students, normally distributed with a mean of 80. 
I then created a classification "1" (passing) for the top 300 students, which based on the seed is a test score of 80.87808591534409.

(Obviously we don't really need machine learning for this, as this means anyone with a test score higher than 80.87808591534409 passes the class. But I want to build a model that accurately predicts this, so that I can start adding new input features and expand my classification beyond, pass/fail).

Next I created a test set in the same way, and classified these students using the classification threshold previously computed for the training set (80.87808591534409).

Then, as you can see below or in the linked Jupyter notebook, I created a model that takes one input feature and returns two results (a probability for the zero index classification (fail) and a probability for one index classification (pass).

Then I trained it on the training data set. But as you can see the loss never really improves per iteration. It just kind of hovers at 0.6.

[image]

Finally, I ran the trained model on the test data set and generated predictions.

I plotted the results as follows:

[image]

The green line represents the actual (not the predicted) classifications of the test set. 
The blue line represents the probability of 0 index outcome (failing) and the orange line represents the probability of the 1 index outcome (passing).

As you can see they remain flat. If my model is working, I would have expected these lines to trade places at the threshold where the actual data switches from failing to passing.

I imagine I could be doing a lot of things wrong, but if anyone has time to look at the code below and give me some advice I would be grateful.

I've created a public working example of my attempt [here](https://colab.research.google.com/drive/1g3-gudyF5AEPaLyKH0HDFom43WAWB4WD#scrollTo=36KH-jVCgK5z).
And I've included the current code below.

The problem I'm having is that the model training seems to get stuck in computing the loss, and as a result, it reports that every student in my testing set (all 1,000 students fail) no matter what their test result is, which is obviously wrong.

```py
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import tensorflow as tf
import tensorflow_hub as hub
import tensorflow_datasets as tfds
from tensorflow.keras import Sequential
from tensorflow.keras.layers import Dense

print("Version: ", tf.__version__)
print("Eager mode: ", tf.executing_eagerly())
print("Hub version: ", hub.__version__)
print("GPU is", "available" if tf.config.experimental.list_physical_devices("GPU") else "NOT AVAILABLE")

## Create data
# Set Seed
np.random.seed(0)
# Create 1000 test scores normally distributed with a range of 2 with a mean of 80
train_exam_scores = np.sort(np.random.normal(80,2,1000))
# Create classification; top 300 pass the class (classification of 1), bottom 700 do not class (classification of 0)
train_labels = np.array([0. for i in range(700)])
train_labels = np.append(train_labels, [1. for i in range(300)])

print("Point at which test scores correlate with passing class: {}".format(train_exam_scores[701]))
print("computed point with seed of 0 should be: 80.87808591534409")
print("Plot point at which test scores correlate with passing class")
## Plot view
plt.plot(train_exam_scores)
plt.plot(train_labels)
plt.show()

#create another set of 1000 test scores with different seed (10)
np.random.seed(10)
test_exam_scores = np.sort(np.random.normal(80,2,1000))
# create classification labels for the new test set based on passing rate of 80.87808591534409 determined above
test_labels = np.array([])
for index, i in enumerate(test_exam_scores):
    if (i >= 80.87808591534409):
        test_labels = np.append(test_labels, 1)
    else:
        test_labels = np.append(test_labels, 0)
plt.plot(test_exam_scores)
plt.plot(test_labels)
plt.show()

print(tf.shape(train_exam_scores))
print(tf.shape(train_labels))
print(tf.shape(test_exam_scores))
print(tf.shape(test_labels))
train_dataset = tf.data.Dataset.from_tensor_slices((train_exam_scores, train_labels))
test_dataset = tf.data.Dataset.from_tensor_slices((test_exam_scores, test_labels))
BATCH_SIZE = 5
SHUFFLE_BUFFER_SIZE = 1000

train_dataset = train_dataset.shuffle(SHUFFLE_BUFFER_SIZE).batch(BATCH_SIZE)
test_dataset = test_dataset.batch(BATCH_SIZE)

# view example of feature to label correlation, values above 80.87808591534409 are classified as 1, those below are classified as 0
features, labels = next(iter(train_dataset))
print(features)
print(labels)

# create model with first layer to take 1 input feature per student; and output layer of two values (percentage of 0 or 1 classification)
model = tf.keras.Sequential([
  tf.keras.layers.Dense(10, activation=tf.nn.relu, input_shape=(1,)),  # input shape required
  tf.keras.layers.Dense(10, activation=tf.nn.relu),
  tf.keras.layers.Dense(2)
])

# Test untrained model on training features; should produce nonsense results
predictions = model(features)
print(tf.nn.softmax(predictions[:5]))
print("Prediction: {}".format(tf.argmax(predictions, axis=1)))

loss_object = tf.keras.losses.SparseCategoricalCrossentropy(from_logits=True)

optimizer = tf.keras.optimizers.SGD(learning_rate=0.1)

model.compile(optimizer=optimizer,
              loss=loss_object,
              metrics=['categorical_accuracy'])


#train model 

model.fit(train_dataset,
                epochs=20,
                validation_data=test_dataset,
                verbose=1)

#make predictions on test scores from test_dataset
predictions = model.predict(test_dataset)

tf.nn.softmax(predictions[:1000])

tf.argmax(predictions, axis=1)

# I anticipate that the predictions would show a higher probability for index position [0] (classification 0, "did not pass") 
#until it reaches a value greater than 80.87808591534409 
# which in the test data with a seed of 10 should be the value at the 683 index position
# but at this point I would expect there to be a higher probability for index position [1] (classification 1), "did pass" 
# because it is obvious from the data that anyone who scores higher than 80.87808591534409 should pass.
# Thus in the chart below I would expect the lines charting the probability to switch precisely at the point where the test classifications shift.
# However this is not the case. All predictions are the same for all 1000 values.
plt.plot(tf.nn.softmax(predictions[:1000]))
plt.plot(test_labels)
plt.show()
```

Answer (score 0):

The main issue here: Use `softmax` activation in the last layer, not separetely outside the model. Change the final layer to:

```
tf.keras.layers.Dense(2, activation="softmax")
```

Secondly, for two hidden layers with relu, 0.1 may be too high a learning rate. Try with a lower rate of maybe 0.01 or 0.001.

Another thing to try is to divide the input by 100, to get inputs in the range [0, 1]. This makes training easier, since the update step does not heavily modify the weights.

Comment: many thanks. I tried those changes. I also thought it might be a problem that my training data labels were a 1-d Array, e.g [0, 1, 0, 1, 0, 0] etc when I was asking for 2 outputs. So I changed the training labels array to 2-d [[0, 1], [0, 1], [1,0], [1,0]]. The [0,1] means false for "failing" and true for "passing". The [1,0] means true for "failing", false for "passing". But unfortunately it didn't seem to help. Lots still to learn I guess.  If interested, you can see my changes here: https://colab.research.google.com/drive/1g3-gudyF5AEPaLyKH0HDFom43WAWB4WD#scrollTo=KA2qNg-XgK5v.